# DataTable Filter Property Not Working when Page Reloads in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

**This is my aspx Code that works fine **

```
<div class="col-xs-12">

                <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" class="form-control" placeholdr="Enter the key to search" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" class="btn btn-info btn-flat" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Please Select a Category" Text="Go"  OnClientClick="javascript:return  Validation();" runat="server" />
                    <div id="divMsg" style="display: none;">
                        <img src="../Images/Preloader_3.gif" width="40" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!--Select Book Details | OLM_Se_Book -->
        <table id="example1" class="table table-responsive" >

       </table>
```

**Ajax**

```
$("[id$=btnSearch]").click(function () {
                var v = $("[id$=rdSearch]").find("input:checked").length;
                if (v == 0) {
                    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
                    return false;
                }
                val = $("[id$=rdSearch]").find("input:checked").val();
                val1 = document.getElementById('<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>').value;
                if (val != "" && val1 != "") {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'Home2.aspx',
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: 'Radio='+encodeURIComponent(val)+'&Txt='+encodeURIComponent(val1),
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function (response) {
                            $('#example1').html(response);
                            $('#example1').DataTable();// This code work when pages loads but not working when it reloads
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);

                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            // alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });

                }


            });
        });
```

DataTable works fine on my first click .But when click again data loads fine but filtering and sorting not working properly.
Here the data loads from the page **Home2.aspx** that works well all time. Please Help .

Comment: When data Table is initialise it creates wrapper divs and inserts your table inside the wrapper divs. So the second time when you try to initialise datatable the table is already inside wrapper divs. So it does not get initialised properly.Hence your filter is not working properly.

Comment: @VigneshPandi thank you for your replay. Can you Suggest any solution for it??

Comment: Use the second solution mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If your table Id #example the wrapper div id will be #example_wrapper.
So In order for this to work delete the entire wrapper div and add your table tag again along with response data and perform initailaisation.

```
  $('#example_wrapper').after('<table id="example"></table>');
 $('#example_wrapper').remove();
$('#example').html(response);
$('#example').DataTable();
```

Or the better solution will be
To use before applying response data:

```
if($('#example').hasClass('dataTable')){
    var table=$('#example').DataTable(); 
     table.destroy();
}
     $('#example').html(response);
     $('#example').DataTable();
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Its works as my wish. Thanks a lot sir . But the **table style** lost when its reloads. Filtering and searching works properly for me .Thank you sir thanks a lot

Comment: To prevent table style use the code in the ajax success :

if($('#example').hasClass('dataTable')){
    var table=$('#example').DataTable(); 
     table.destroy();
}
     $('#example').html(response);
     $('#example').DataTable();

Comment: $('#example1_wrapper').after('<table id="example1" ** class="table table-responsive" **></table>');
                            $('#example1_wrapper').remove();
                            $('#example1').html(response);
                            $('#example1').DataTable(); By adding the code i get my output as my wish . Thank you sir ..